# How can I automatic start and reload index.js in nodeJs, when I do changes on my frontend - Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular

I know, that I must to change my package.json file, but I do not understand how.
I try to use "watch" in package.json scripts, but it did't work.
Please, help me. I just start to learn Angular and NodeJs.
Sorry for my bad English and simple question.
Now I always reload my server with nodemon index.js and have problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBoJS.png)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "node": "^17.1.0"
  },
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have `index.js` inside the `src` folder

***With Environment Setup***

```
  .
  . 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "***env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env*** nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
  },
 .
 .
```

**Without Environment** and want to track changes in file extensions other than `js`.

If you want to auto start the server on the `js, hbs, html` files changes.

```
  .
  . 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./config/dev.env nodemon src/index.js -e js,hbs,html",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
  },
 .
 .
```

**Without Environment and track only `js` file**

the following section shows commands  without environment set-up.
Here we have completely ignore `-e` argument as we do not want to auto-start server upon changes in the files other than `.js`.

```
  .
  . 
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
  },
 .
 .
```

In the command prompt. Run the following command:

```
$npm run dev
```

**Note:**-you can ignore `start` and `test` keys in above solution

Comment: This did't work. The same error, which was on screenshoot
`
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "env-cmd -f ./config/test.env jest --watch"
  }    
`
First and second did't work. Problem with env-cmd. 
"*** env-cmd" is not internal or external
command, executable program, or batch file

Comment: 1st and 2nd will only work if you have set up the dev/prod/staging environment. Refs: npmjs.com/package/env-cmd. Ref to set up an medium.com/the-node-js-collection/… – 
Abhishek
 37 mins

Answer (score 0):

just use this command inside the script
"dev": "nodemon src/index.js"

and remove the script tag
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"